# Cannot install ANY packages because of Python

Tags: python, apt-get, raspbian

I cannot install any packages with `apt-get` on Raspbian (Debian) because of stupid Python packages.

I tried to `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
but even  then I’m getting these errors!

Messages:

```
Setting up python3 (3.4.2-2) ...
running python rtupdate hooks for python3.4...
dpkg-query: package 'gdebi-core' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of gdebi-core
error running python rtupdate hook gdebi-core
dpkg-query: package 'python3-uno' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of python3-uno
error running python rtupdate hook python3-uno
dpkg: error processing package python3 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 4
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-gi:
 python3-gi depends on python3 (>= 3.4~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-gi depends on python3 (<< 3.5); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-gi (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of unattended-upgrades:
 unattended-upgrades depends on python3; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package unattended-upgrades (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-software-properties:
 python3-software-properties depends on python3 (>= 3.2.3-3~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-software-properties depends on unattended-upgrades; however:
  Package unattended-upgrades is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-software-properties (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dh-python:
 dh-python depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package dh-python (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of software-properties-common:
 software-properties-common depends on python3 (>= 3.2.3-3~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 software-properties-common depends on python3-gi; however:
  Package python3-gi is not configured yet.
 software-properties-common depends on python3-software-properties; however:
  Package python3-software-properties is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package software-properties-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-apt:
 python3-apt depends on python3 (<< 3.5); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-apt depends on python3 (>= 3.4~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-apt (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-dbus:
 python3-dbus depends on python3 (>= 3.3~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-dbus depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-dbus depends on python3 (<< 3.5); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-dbus (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-software-properties:
 python-software-properties depends on unattended-upgrades; however:
  Package unattended-upgrades is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-software-properties (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3
 python3-gi
 unattended-upgrades
 python3-software-properties
 dh-python
 software-properties-common
 python3-apt
 python3-dbus
 python-software-properties
```

Answer (score 5):

Switch back to python 2.7

Use the command :

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

If you get an error :

```
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for python
```

Update your `update-alternatives` as follow :

```
ls /usr/bin | grep python | columns
```

sample output:

```
dh_python2  idle-python3.4  python2     python3     python3.4m
dh_python3  python      python2.7   python3.4   python3m
```

You have the `python2.7` and `python3.4` , run:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.7 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.4 2
```

See `update-alternatives --help`

Now you can run;

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

sample output:

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative python (providing /usr/bin/python).

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/python3.4   2         auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/python2.7   1         manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/python3.4   2         manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 1
```

To make the `python2.7` as default select 1

Run :

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt update
```

use the command `history` to get the latest installed `*-python` package which break your system (e,g; `python-scapy`) then remove it:

```
sudo apt-get remove python-scapy
```

Once done you can revert back to `python3.4` using the `update-alternative` command

Comment: HAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHA I thought for once I had found a solution that might work instead of producing nothing but errors that the author didn't bother to mention. `-bash: columns: command not found`. Of course. Of course! I'll just google that error, so I can find "solutions" to that problem, which instead of fixing it, will produce still more unexpected errors, all "solutions" of which will produce still more errors. I know this, because it's been a week of this so far.

Comment: I tried it without `columns`, and got all the way to `sudo dpkg --configure -a`... which of course, DOES NOT WORK and instead returns only the exact error I came to this page to solve. `Processing was halted because there were too many errors`. My god, Kafka couldn't have come up with a more exquisite torture than trying to get a clean stock install of Debian upgraded to the next version. BTW, some information on how looking at my command history tells me why python is messed up would be helpful, too.